# How to set up BrowserSync and/or Angular $http to work together without cors issues

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, same-origin-policy, browser-sync

I have BrowerSync setup who serves my AngularJS application. It works great till I want to call my REST-API which is MS Web-Api project running on IIS Express.

So, I have JS application running on locahost:3000 calling through $http rest-api run localhost:4000 so I do have CORS issues.

How to set up BrowserSync or any other software (on Windows 8) to get rid these issues?

The perfect way to me would be some grunt profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did, and what was the easiest thing to do without touching anything was running chrome without cors.

`PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application> .\chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-websecurity`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on two separate domains, you will have CORS anyway.
What you could do is enabling CORS on your API with `config.EnableCors()` on your `WebApiConfig.cs`

More info here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api